# How to send a 401 as unauthorized user and a 404 if a database query returned a null object in a Spring boot webapp REST API controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I'm using a bit of a personalized security back-end due to the nature of the app and was trying out how to implement a few simple error returns in my REST API controller. It's simple enough to do in a html page controller like I have in the following:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/home.html")
    public String home(Model model) {
        String redirect = "home";

        if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isCanAccessService()) {
            redirect = "unauthorized";
        }       
        return redirect;
    }
}
```

I can easily just redirect it to the unauthorized page that I made since I'm returning the string value here. However, when I go to a REST API it's not as simple:

```
@RestController
public class bagelController {

    @Autowired
    private bagelService bagelService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/rest/bagel/search")
    public Bagel searchBagel (@RequestParam(value = "bagel", required = false) String bagel, 
            @RequestParam(value = "bagelInd", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int bagelInd) {

        Bagel bagel;
        if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isBagelEditAccess()) {
            bagel = null;
            // I want to return a 401 or direct to my unathorized page if I get an invalid user here.
        }
        else {
            bagel = bagelService.getbagel(bagel, bagelInd);
            // if my bagel object returns null, I want to return a 404 or direct to a 404 not
               found page here.
        } 
        return bagel; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this.

```java
    @GetMapping("/rest/bagel/search")
    public ResponseEntity<Bagel> searchBagel (@RequestParam(value = "bagel", required = false) String bagel, 
            @RequestParam(value = "bagelInd", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int bagelInd) {

        Bagel bagel = null;
        if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isBagelEditAccess()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
        else {
            bagel = bagelService.getbagel(bagel, bagelInd);
            if(bagel == null) { 
              return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
        } 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(bagel); 
    }
```

Comment: So, this works perfectly but I have a couple questions.
1. I'd like to personally only have one return statement if possible. Is the ResponseEntity something I can use like an object and just set that equal to each of the different returns (401,404, okay) and then just return the final one at the end?

2. I like how the unauthorized shows the 401 error, but is there a way I can link it to my actual "unauthorized.html?"

Comment: ```final ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder responseEntity;

        String bagel = null;
        if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isBagelEditAccess()) {
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        else {
            bagel = bagelService.getbagel(bagel, bagelInd);
            if(bagel == null) {
                responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            } else {
                responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        }
        return responseEntity.build();```

Comment: Yep! I actually just figured that out and got the build running right before I refreshed this to see your comment. Much appreciated on that though, and no worries on the formatting! Guess I just need to figure out a way to get it to link to my unauthorized page now.

Comment: Try by adding an HttpServletResponse parameter to your Handler Method then call `response.sendRedirect("some-url");` to inject response just add this parameter in your controller -> `HttpServletResponse response` Spring will inject the response for you

Comment: Alright, that definitely worked as well. I should probably make a new question at this point, but if I wanted to log the unauthorized user that tried to access the api, would there be a way to do that @CodeScale?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a [ControllerAdvice](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/use-restcontrolleradvice-new-features-spring-framework-4-3) which handles exceptions and their HTTP return code. Then you can annotate a method in it the following way for example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchEntityException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

This will return a 404 code every time it encounters a `NoSuchEntityException` (custom exception). So you can throw such an exception when you check if an entity is null. You can use the same thing for 401 or any other HTTP code as well.

Comment: I'll definitely have to look into implementing these "Make your own exception" things in the future. It looks really interesting and extremely customizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom exceptions within your application for this scenario like BagelNotFoundException and UnauthorizedException. Both these custom exception classes can extend Exception class or more specific classes from java exception hierarchy. You can annotate these custom exception classes with @ResponseStatus annotation to provide the http status code that should be sent in the response.

Next, you need to throw the objects of these exceptions within your controller.

Once this exception is thrown, an exception handler should be present within your application to take care of these exceptions. The same can be defined using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler within your custom exception handler classes.

This way you'll be able to send appropriate response to the client, and the client application needs to redirect the user to error pages based on the response code received.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This custom exception stuff looks/sounds really cool. I'll have to look into that once I get more in depth in the project so I can do more creative things.